# Oracle 12C: Creating Table so that most recent records inserted are on top by default

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle and for the sake of learning, I need to **know how to create a table so that the newest records inserted are at the top**.

In TSQL: I will do a *`CLUSTERED INDEX`* with Decrement on a Unique Column.

Using Oracle SQL Developer, below is a sample table: I want the record with the most recent *`ORDER_DATE`* to be on top. *Note: The Date is stored as a string.* I also tried using REVERSE on the Primary Key column but that did not do it.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS 
(
  ORDER_NBR NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY 
  INCREMENT BY 10 
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
  MINVALUE 135790864211 
  CACHE 20 NOT NULL 

, CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, ORDER_TYPE NUMBER NOT NULL 
, ORDER_DATE NVARCHAR2(27) NOT NULL 
, RETURN_DATE NVARCHAR2(27) 
, CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_NBR_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    ORDER_NBR
  ));

 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_ORDER_DATE_ORDERS ON ORDERS (ORDER_DATE DESC);
 CREATE INDEX IDX_RETURN_DATE_ORDERS ON ORDERS (RETURN_DATE DESC);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I'm not sure what you mean by the records being at the "top".  Are you always wanting the results sorted in a certain way?

Comment: "Note: The Date is stored as a string." - start by fixing that. Use proper date types for dates and time. The only thing that resembles a SQL Server clustered index is called an IOT in Oracle (Index-organised table). But why do you need that here?

Comment: Lets assumed two records are inserted into the above table: The record with the most recent date will be on top of the table, meaning the top row by default. Like an `ORDER BY COLUMN DESC`

Comment: Is using an order by clause not an option?  If you want rows to always return in a certain order, I would recommend putting a view over the order that has the order by clause you would like to specify.

Comment: You **must** use an `order by` clause in your queries regardless of how the data is physically stored (even if you use an IOT). Without an order clause, you're not guaranteed anything. There is no workaround. Use an order by clause.

Comment: My first question is why do you want to do this? Just because you have done this in SQL Server it may make no sense to do it in Oracle

Comment: @Mat you ought to make it an answer

Comment: No, I am not trying to compare the two. My question is about learning. I want to understand. I used TSQL as a reference to explain what I was trying to do. I shall take Mat's advise. Again, I am simply trying to understand.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy, there is no "order" per se when the data is stored in the database. Ordering data is done by your query as Mat has explained. Good question though. Look into the concept of Oracle's [ROWID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) and it may answer some of your questions.